# How can I make this operations with a file in C?

Tags: c, file

I have this file that has just numbers:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I've made this function to write into the file:

```
void change(char* file) {

    int count = 0;
    FILE* arquive = fopen (file,"a+");

    char line[256];
    memset(line,0,strlen(line));
    char auxLine[256];
    memset(auxLine,0,strlen(auxLine));

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), arquive) != NULL) {
        if (count == 1) {
            memset(auxLine,0,strlen(auxLine));
            strncpy(auxLine, line, sizeof line);
            fprintf(arquive, "%s", auxLine);
        } else {
            count++;
        }
    }

}
```

The output on the file:

```
5 6 7 8 9 105 6 7 8 9 10
10
    2   10
    2   10
9   9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          16   16    NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

But whenever I try to append a string to the file using fprintf, it prints a lot of trash. I've tried using memset to clean whats inside, but without any success.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you forget to null-terminate your string?

Comment: I tested by initializing it with "\0", but nothing

Comment: `char line[256]; memset(line,0,strlen(line));` is wrong, since `line` is uninitialized, so the behavior of `strlen()` is *undefined behavior*. Same with `char auxLine[256]; memset(auxLine,0,strlen(auxLine));`  Use `sizeof()` instead of `strlen()` in this case.  Also, inside your loop, the `memset(auxLine,0,strlen(auxLine));` is also wrong, and unnecessary, so just remove it completely

Comment: Tested it using sizeof instead, still throwing garbage at the file.

Comment: @TryMe I don't see how that is possible given the code shown, once you fix the above issues. `fgets()` guarantees the output `char[]` is null-terminated on success, so `line` will be null-terminated inside the loop, and since `line` and `auxLine` are the same size, `strncpy()` will guarantee `auxLine` is null-terminated when passed to `fprintf()`. Of course, `auxLine` is completely redundant in the code shown, so you could get rid of it completely and just pass `line` directly to `fprintf()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Totally agree with you. I don't know whats happening. It's weird because it prints correctly the line on the end of the file, but the rest is all garbage

Comment: "*I don't know whats happening*" - that is what a debugger is meant for. Use one. "*but the rest is all garbage*" - what "rest" are you referring to? Can you show the actual output you are looking at? You do realize that you are opening the file in append mode, but you are not writing any delimiter, like a line break, between multiple runs of your program, don't you? If your input file does not end in a line break, `line` won't have a line break in it when copied to `auzLine` and then printed by `fprintf()`.

Comment: Added the output, it has some null too, but i can put it there.

Comment: I've tried to put a break, inside of the if, and it isn't working. Yeah, I came here exactly because I can't understand what's happening lol

Comment: If you wish to initialize all elements of a char array to `0`, you do not need to use `memset` (which won't work properly with `strlen` as mentioned already). You can initialize it like so: `char line[256] = {0};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *fopen(..., "a+")* -- Open for reading and writing.   The stream is positioned at the *end of the file*.   So, your while loop is never entered.
2. The copies and memsets are meaningless, the code below is equivalent:

```
void change(char* file) {

    int count = 0;
    FILE* arquive = fopen (file,"a+");

    char line[256];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), arquive) != NULL) {
        if (count == 1) {
            fputs(line, arquive);
        } else {
            count++;
        }
    }

}
```

3. The version below is probably closer to what you want:

```
void change(char* file) {

    int count = 0;
    FILE* arquive = fopen (file,"a+");
    FILE *src     = fopen(file, "r");
    char line[256];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), src) != NULL) {
        if (count == 1) {
            fputs(line, arquive);
        } else {
            count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(src);
    fclose(arquive);
}
```

4. You may be playing with fire reading and writing the file you are appending.  But it seems to work for small files at least.

Comment: Thanks so much, mevets! It's not inserting garbage anymore. Thanks!

Comment: Nitpick: The ISO C standard does not guarantee that the same file can be opened multiple times. According to [§7.21.3 ¶8 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p8), it is implementation-defined whether this is supported. However, it is probably supported on most common platforms.

Comment: What did you think #4 was saying?